# What is the name of the Lego product that snaps together with knobs?

Tags: part-identification

I remember owning a very strange Lego set, but have forgotten the name.

The pieces were similar to Technic parts, but different. They were green rounded frames and connected using purple squares with knobs. I do not recall them being able to directly connect to classic Lego bricks.

The set I owned was some sort of space ship. It came with a motor that made parts of it spin.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have any idea as to when that set came out?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I ended up finding my old instruction book. The parts were called [Lego Znap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Znap).

[image]

[image]

It still blows my mind that these things exist.

Comment: No spaceships *and* no relation to TECHNIC? If this was the answer you wanted, the question should have had better clues.

Comment: @Dori, the holes in the beams do suggest a Technic aesthetic, though not compatibility.

Comment: What do you mean no relation to Technic? These holes are Technic holes in their own right; plus, they did even use the same motor, which made it a very cost-efficient way to get some when LEGO ditched ZNAP altogether. Sadly, these were usually the bad batch of motors.

Comment: @Dori I had forgotten most of the details since I haven't heard about it in 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of the BIONICLE line?

> BIONICLE was a theme with series of sets using some of the TECHNIC pieces created by LEGO in 2001 to 2010. It is usually attributed to the TECHNIC line due to the inclusion of TECHNIC specific elements and building-styles although being a largely independent product series.
>   — [BIONICLE - Brickipedia, the LEGO Wiki](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/BIONICLE)

[image: By Huhu at de.wikipedia Public domain, via Wikimedia Commons]

Comment: I don't recall any Bionicle spaceships, but who knows?

Comment: @PeterDC The second to last year of Bionicle actually had three models that could be called spaceships (and were actually my favorite sets of the entire series): 8942 Jetrax T6, 8941 Roctoh T3, and 8943 Axalara T9.